# Importing contacts from addressbook in android is slow?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I have written code for importing all the contacts with details `(Name,Mobile number,DOB,anniversary and email address)` from device addressbook to my application database.The code is running fine and getting all details but its a very slow process for large number of contacts.For example on `samsumg Galaxy s4` with `8000 contacts` it takes upto 20 minutes.The code I am using is following:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
int count = cur.getCount();
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
first_name = "";
first_name = "";

                    name = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    first_name = name == null ? "" : name;


                    // birthday
                    Cursor bdc = cr
                            .query(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                    new String[] { Event.DATA },
                                    android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = "
                                            + id
                                            + " AND "
                                            + Data.MIMETYPE
                                            + " = '"
                                            + Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                            + "' AND "
                                            + Event.TYPE
                                            + " = "
                                            + Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY,
                                    null,
                                    android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    if (bdc.getCount() > 0) {
                        while (bdc.moveToNext()) {
                            birthDate = bdc.getString(0);
                        }
                    }

                  if (bdc != null)
                    bdc.close();

                Cursor ann = cr
                        .query(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[] { Event.DATA },
                                android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                        + " = "
                                        + id
                                        + " AND "
                                        + Data.MIMETYPE
                                        + " = '"
                                        + Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                        + "' AND "
                                        + Event.TYPE
                                        + " = "
                                        + Event.TYPE_ANNIVERSARY,
                                null,
                                android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (ann.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (ann.moveToNext()) {
                        anniversaryDate = ann.getString(0);
                    }
                }
               if (ann != null)
                    ann.close();


                Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                if (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    email1 = cur1
                            .getString(cur1
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    if (email1 == null)
                        email1 = "";
     if (cur1 != null)
            cur1.close();

if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                    null);
                    if (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                        phone = pCur
                                .getString(pCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        if (phone == null)
                            phone = "";
                    }
```

**How Can I improve my above code to run more faster?Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong in my code?**

Answer (score 0):

put them in a new thread, after you get the result, give it to `Handler` to display on UI; It will not make your code faster, but at least, it won't stuck your UI.